# Не работает симулятор iOS в xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

как можно проверить симулятор в xcode самым простым способом 
Работает он или нет. Смотрел видео урок зделал все как есть, но показывает белый экран, так же создал новый проект и добавил туда объект View покрасив его в другой цвет. так же белый экран.

Я так понимаю все, что добавляется в storyboard должно быть видно

Я новичек в xcode и незнаю как его проверить корректно он работает или нет

Comment: xcode -> open developer tool -> simulator

Comment: нет, я устанавливаю объект (View) в storyboard , например перекрашиваю в красный, запускаю симулятор ничего не происходит. Как я понял должен появиться красный квадрат внезависимости есть код или нет. Так ли это.

Comment: это то так. давайте сначала попробуйте просто запустить симулятор, без приложения.

Answer (score 2):

Здесь есть несколько вариантов ошибки,

1. **Нету констрейнсов**, маловероятно, но возможно у тебя сбиты Constrains. Для решения данной проблемы выдели свой ViewController и снизу, на панельке, нажми на треугольник, а далее Add Missing Constrains
2. **Не задан Initial View Controller**, возможно у тебя не задан начальный VC. Выдели его и в правой панели выдели чекбокс "As InitialViewController"
3. Также попробуй проверить на девайсе, если есть такая возможность. Так ты сузишь круг решений

Надеюсь помог, чем смог. Скорее склоняюсь ко второму пункту.

Comment: Нашел, вот только он не дает возможности добавить констраин. я так понимаю это значек типа звездных войн внизу только с уголком?

Comment: @jcmax Возможно, треугольник с двумя вертикальными полосками по бокам